# Deploy Python Modules on Heroku?

Tags: python-2.7, heroku, word2vec

I have a problem deploying python modules on Heroku.
It's based on python2.

requirements.txt file:

```
Flask==0.11.1
Jinja2==2.8
MarkupSafe==0.23
Werkzeug==0.11.10
click==6.6
gunicorn==19.6.0
itsdangerous==0.24
requests==2.10.0
wsgiref==0.1.2
konlpy==0.4.4
gensim==2.1.0
```

The modules that I'm having trouble uploading is konlpy and gensim.
I already installed all the modules on virtual environment. I also set the buildpack for gensim (not konlpy).

The error log is:

```
2017-06-10T08:56:17.851884+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:56:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2017-06-10T08:56:17.851975+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:56:17 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2017-06-10T08:56:17.946195+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-10T08:56:17.936020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2017-06-10T08:56:55.589601+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/" host=afternoon-beach-22534.herokuapp.com request_id=8e14e22a-b473-4aa8-959e-c26a80f8775e fwd="69.63.188.105" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-10T08:58:15.541365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/" host=afternoon-beach-22534.herokuapp.com request_id=1bd4f45b-1db6-4e24-be10-28b0b62b7c40 fwd="173.252.124.202" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-10T08:59:04.103999+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2017-06-10T08:59:19.881438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app --log-file=-`
2017-06-10T08:59:23.010876+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
2017-06-10T08:59:23.012294+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2017-06-10T08:59:23.020541+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2017-06-10T08:59:23.089805+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2017-06-10T08:59:23.011687+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:42198 (4)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.730044+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520921+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520934+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520936+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520936+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520937+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520938+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520938+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520939+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520940+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520941+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520941+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520942+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520942+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520943+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520944+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520944+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520945+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 8, in <module>
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520946+00:00 app[web.1]:     from konlpy.tag import Twitter; t = Twitter()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520947+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/konlpy/tag/_twitter.py", line 72, in __init__
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520947+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvm.init_jvm(jvmpath)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520948+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/konlpy/jvm.py", line 40, in init_jvm
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520949+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvmpath = jvmpath or jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520949+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 114, in get_default_jvm_path
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520950+00:00 app[web.1]:     return finder.get_jvm_path()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520951+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 121, in get_jvm_path
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520951+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvm = method()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520952+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 164, in _get_from_known_locations
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520953+00:00 app[web.1]:     for home in self.find_possible_homes(self._locations):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520954+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 95, in find_possible_homes
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520954+00:00 app[web.1]:     for childname in sorted(os.listdir(parent)):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520955+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520962+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520962+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520963+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 557, in spawn_worker
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520964+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520964+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520965+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520966+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 136, in load_wsgi
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520966+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520967+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520967+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520968+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520969+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520969+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520970+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520970+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520971+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520972+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 8, in <module>
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520972+00:00 app[web.1]:     from konlpy.tag import Twitter; t = Twitter()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520973+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/konlpy/tag/_twitter.py", line 72, in __init__
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520974+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvm.init_jvm(jvmpath)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520974+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/konlpy/jvm.py", line 40, in init_jvm
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520975+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvmpath = jvmpath or jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520976+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_core.py", line 114, in get_default_jvm_path
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520977+00:00 app[web.1]:     return finder.get_jvm_path()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520977+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 121, in get_jvm_path
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520978+00:00 app[web.1]:     jvm = method()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520979+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 164, in _get_from_known_locations
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520979+00:00 app[web.1]:     for home in self.find_possible_homes(self._locations):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520980+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jpype/_jvmfinder.py", line 95, in find_possible_homes
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520981+00:00 app[web.1]:     for childname in sorted(os.listdir(parent)):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.520981+00:00 app[web.1]: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/jvm'
2017-06-10T08:59:23.521316+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.521493+00:00 app[web.1]: [2017-06-10 08:59:23 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552400+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552442+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 11, in <module>
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552493+00:00 app[web.1]:     sys.exit(run())
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552512+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552559+00:00 app[web.1]:     WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552605+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 192, in run
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552667+00:00 app[web.1]:     super(Application, self).run()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552685+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552727+00:00 app[web.1]:     Arbiter(self).run()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552769+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 218, in run
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552834+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552851+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 331, in halt
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552954+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.552972+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 381, in stop
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553058+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553101+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 231, in handle_chld
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553166+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553182+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 506, in reap_workers
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553314+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2017-06-10T08:59:23.553400+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2017-06-10T08:59:23.748346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-06-10T08:59:36.316423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=POST path="/" host=afternoon-beach-22534.herokuapp.com request_id=e7341e48-6af5-4d10-8d6d-4a485fdda85c fwd="173.252.124.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-06-10T08:59:53.796217+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=afternoon-beach-22534.herokuapp.com request_id=898717bb-1ce1-4c36-97ef-fa844585effb fwd="59.18.254.244" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What I'm trying to do is deploying word2vec on heroku.
Thank you.

Comment: From those error logs, the problem appears to involve `konlpy` and `jpype` – not gensim or word2vec. And specifically, code in package `jpype` is expecting to find a `/usr/lib/jvm' directory on the heroku dyno, but is not. So you'll want to look for hints on how to get `jpype` to work on heroku, and/or get a JVM installed in addition to the Python buildpack.

Comment: Thank you! It seems that JVM installation will solve this problem. Still, I'm not really sure how to install JVM in a python based server. Does simply adding openjdk in the requirements.txt install JVM? Thank you :)

Comment: Python installation routines (as driven by `requirements.txt`) don't usually install non-Python packages (like the JVM). You should search in `jpype` and Heroku help areas for ideas for auto-installing a JVM in a Heroku dyno.

Comment: It seems that jpype does not provide any document about deploying in a online server. Though the problem is not solved, thank you for hinting the cause of the problem. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using jpype on Heroku.  I got it working by adding the Java buildpack from the Heroku 'Settings' dashboard.  Then I added a  pom.xml file to the repository and populated it with the code listed [here](https://gist.github.com/martensjostrand/4131573).  Then redeploy and jpype should be working.  Heroku thinks you're deploying both a Python app and a Java app, so it calls Maven to handle your java code (which doesn't exist :D )  The pom.xml gives Maven something to do during deployment (Heroku fails the deployment if pom.xml doesn't exists or is truly empty), but ultimately doesn't do anything when the app is live...at least that's what I think is happening.  In any case JVM should be available for jpype to access.  I know this is late but I only ran into this problem today, maybe it helps.

Cheers,

Tim